# How to make one project build before all others?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I know you can set Build Dependencies for projects in Visual Studio and that will make the dependency build before the other projects.  However, I have a project that all others will depend on (including new ones that may be added in the future), and so I'd rather just say "this project must build first, before all others" without bothering to set a dependency for every other project.  Is there a way to do this in VS?

Comment: Do the other projects reference this project (`<ProjectReference>`)? Build Dependencies currently cause issues with NuGet restores.. (fixed for 2.0 / VS 15.3 AFAIK)

Comment: So even more reason to find a way to do it other than using dependencies.

Comment: On the commandline you could easily use a 'master' build file which first builds one project then the rest. In theory you could build such file as well from VS but it won't play nice with using a .sln etc. I doubt there are any other options (not involving editing each project seperately) for the rest: a .sln is a rather dumb container which lists projects and dependencies and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this in VS?

**Visual Studio calculates the build order according to your dependence**. Like project A depends on project B, Visual Studio will build B prior to A. So if you want to make one project build before all others, you could not avoid this bothering setting or Visual Studio could not get the build order, will build in the error order.

In order to avoid set a dependency for every other project, you can right-click on your solution and find the Project Dependencies menu item:

[image]

The dialog that opens will allow you to set build dependencies and show you the calculated build order (you can affect the order by changing the dependencies).

In this case, you can set a dependency for every other project at once, no need to set for each one, but for new ones that may be added in the future, you still need to do the settings after added.